# Amazon S3 for Media Storage for Restful API

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a REST API that supports a multi-user React App that I have been running on an EC2 instance for a while and I am moving into uploading photos/pdfs that will be attached to specific users. I have been able to accomplish this in testing using EFS which I had provisioned to the same EC2 instance I had the API on but I am looking to move towards S3.

When I was testing it out using EFS, I would send everything through the REST API, the user would do a POST and then the API would store the file in EFS along with the metadata for where the file was stored in my DB, then in order to retrieve the data the user would do a GET to the REST API and the server would fetch the data from EFS based on metadata in the DB.

I am wondering what is the usual use case for S3? Do I still have to send everything through my REST API if I want to be sure that users only have access to the pdfs/images that they are supposed to or is there a way for me to ensure their identity and directly request the resources from S3 on the front-end and just allow my API to return a list of S3 urls for the files?

The particular use case I have in mind is making it so users are able to upload profile pictures and then when a user searches for another user by name, all of the profile pictures of the users returned in the query of users are able to be displayed in the list of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "normal" way to deal with this particular situation - either could make sense depending on your needs.

Here are some options:

### Option 1

It's possible to safely allow users to access resources **directly** from S3 by using [AWS STS to generate temporary credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html) that your users can utilise to [access the S3 APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionToken.html).

### Option 2

If your happy for the pics to be public, you could configure a [bucket as a static website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) and simply use those public URLs in your web application.

### Option 3

Use [Cloudfront to serve private content](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html) from your S3 buckets.